# Finding the largest functional value of a function on a specified interval

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

The largest functional value of the function $\mathrm{f: y = \frac{x+1}{x}}$ on the interval $[1, 2]$ is:

$(A)$ $1$

$(B)$  $3/2$

$(C)$ $2$

$(D)$ The function f does not have a maximum on the interval $[1, 2]$.

Why is $x = 2$ the correct answer instead of $x = 1$, given that when $x = 2$, the result is $1.5$, when $x = 1$, the result is $2$, and when $x = \frac32$, the result is $1.66$?

Comment: Note that they are asking for the largest function value, not the location of this largest value. You’re correct that $(x+1)/x$ has its maximum at $1$, but its *value* at $1$ is $2$.